# Post deployment pod creation/deletion based on service request

Tags: go, kubernetes, runtime, operator-keyword, kubernetes-pod

We have .Net application which has to be deployed in K8 cluster. We use a  Golang based operator which deploys with one pod (first pod) and starts service request.

We have a requirement to start new pods other than the first pod (which was created during deployment) based on requests. Those start service request of its own. Let's call these pods P1, P2, P3 and Pn. These new pods are not replicas but are individual services with their own configuration.

So I am planning to build a new operator (second operator) which starts working post deployment of the first operator and will create new pods during runtime. But I am stuck at logic to achieve this. Can someone give me some idea to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Nanda K S  It entirely depends on what exactly is the complete details of what you want to build. I saw the implementations given by Fritz that also looks good. If you want a simple way.  Otherwise you can go for your own Custom Resource Definition and you will get more control over it.

Answer (score 0):

Creating K8s deployments dynamically, e.g. triggered by service calls. is **nothing that K8s supports out of the box**.

You will have to come up with an application that has **extensive RBAC rights**, as well as the means to **store K8s configuration** and **deploy that configuration on demand**, e.g. once a REST endpoint was called.

Since this is a requirement that regularly pops up, I have created an [open-source project](https://github.com/fritzduchardt/k8scrud) that shows how it can be done. Please feel free to use this as inspiration or directly.

Comment: Hello Fritz, thanks for your reply and project seems really matching our objective. But still I wanted to achieve the same using operator pattern (Go). Do you think its impossible to achieve this? We wanted separation of responsibility so it is easier for us if we assign this responsibility to K8 operator component than building new application to solve the purpose.

Comment: Hi Nanda, from the documentation it sure seems possible. I would not be surprised if under the hood you still require a Pod such as provided by k8scrud. Feel free to add on to my project - I would be happy to collaborate on that.